# woocommerce credit card payment gateway not showing up in Payment gateways page

Tags: paypal, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am using paypal standart not pro or advanced.
So  before i was able to select credit card payment gateway , i had some issues with woocommerce - it caused 500 server error but i managed to get it going and there were a lot of changes made related to website,but everything is nice no error right now, but now i cant see the credit card gateway. I thought that maybe i have messed up some files and i simply disabled then uninstalled (in woocommerce tools section "Remove post types on uninstall" was selected and saved) the woocommerce plugin and installed it again , but again nothing happened ,i still cant see credit card payment gateway.

[image]

Before there was a credit card gateway
[image]
 By the paypal image were credit card images

Here is System report

#### WordPress Environment

Home URL: http://samplewebsite.com (not my real websites name)
Site URL: http://samplewebsite.com
WC Version: 2.3.7
WC Database Version: 2.3.7
Log Directory Writable: ✔ /home1/lauroskr/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/
WP Version: 4.1.1
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 96 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
Language: en_US

#### Server Environment

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 5.4.38
PHP Post Max Size: 8 MB
PHP Time Limit: 30
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.5.40
Max Upload Size: 2 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

#### Server Locale

decimal_point: .
thousands_sep: N/A
mon_decimal_point: N/A
mon_thousands_sep: N/A

#### Active Plugins (8)

All 404 Redirect  to Homepage: by Fakhri Alsadi – 1.3
Contact Form 7: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 4.1.1
Lightweight Social Icons: by Thomas Usborne – 0.2
Meta Slider: by Matcha Labs – 3.3.1
Redirection: by John Godley – 2.3.14
Page Builder by SiteOrigin: by SiteOrigin – 2.1
SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle: by SiteOrigin – 1.2
WooCommerce: by WooThemes – 2.3.7

#### Settings

API Enabled: ✔
Taxes Enabled: –
Shipping Enabled: –
Force SSL: –
Currency: USD ($)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2

#### WC Pages

Shop Base: #101 - /shop/
Cart: #102 - /cart/
Checkout: #103 - /checkout/
My Account: #104 - /my-account/

#### Taxonomies

Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

#### Theme

Name: Vantage
Version: 1.3.4
Author URL: http://siteorigin.com/
Child Theme: ✕ – If you're modifying WooCommerce or a parent theme you didn't build personally we recommend using a child theme. See: How to create a child theme
WooCommerce Support: ✔

#### Templates

Overrides: –

In my paypal account where the money is transferred PayPal Account Optional is set to ON in website payment preferences page.

Also when i proceeded to paypal there was no section to use credit card,only pay with paypal and create paypal account.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely controled by PayPal whether the option to pay via Credit Card is available. You'll need to reach out to PayPal for this. There are no options within WooCommerce that you could change to enable this.

Comment: I will support them and after i get answer i will post it here .

Comment: @LauroSkr And you did you get an answer?